# Is there a way to embed a Published var in one ObservableObject into another ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, observer-pattern, combine

I have a Auth store (an ObservableObject) which stores whether a user has authenticated into the application. I manage the auth store when the user logs in, essentially changing the authentication state from notAuthenticated to authenticated. I use the same state variable in a ViewModel another ObservableObject, which refers to the Auth store singleton object. I think there might be a simpler way to do this than sinking the variable and updating it on the ViewModel (like directly embedding the Auth variable in the ViewModel).

This is a simplified code for the auth store model

```
class Auth: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = Auth()

    @Published var currentState: AuthState = .notAuthenticated

    enum AuthState {
        case notAuthenticated
        case authenticated
    }
}
```

This is the simplified view model

```
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var authState = Auth.shared.currentState

    init() {
    
        Auth.shared.$currentState.sink { newAuthState in
             self.authState = newAuthState
        } // Is there any simple way in which I can skip sinking the publishr
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the simpler way is named *novacula Occami* - entities should not be multiplied without necessity.... or in SwiftUI terms - single source of truth. Just have one authState in one place - `class Auth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good time for dependency injection and as @Asperi mentioned in the comments, having two stateful objects that mirror the same state isn't a great idea anyway...

Something like this is better IMHO:

```
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let authState: AnyPublisher<Auth.AuthState, Never>

    init<P>(authState: P) where P: Publisher, P.Output == Auth.AuthState, P.Failure == Never {
        self.authState = authState.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Then create it in code like:

```
let viewModel = SampleViewModel(authState: Auth.shared.$currentState)
```

For testing, you could inject a test value.

Comment: So I tried to go ahead and patch the pattern I was using in my question like an idiot and  it worked fine initially. But man did it cause me a lot of pain later when I subscribed to it in multiple places and tried to manage all the instances. Finally, coded up a simple DI and it saved me from disaster. Dependency Injection sounds like something you need to stay away from, so I did not even bother trying it. Better late than never